# Getting more than one entry from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find the attack power of a group.

First of all I have:

```
$the_members = mysql_query("  SELECT 
                                `id`
                              FROM
                               `user`
                              WHERE
                                `group` = '".$group."'
                           ")
                              or die(mysql_error());
```

Then we have to find everyone's power, so:

```
$find_members_power = mysql_query("  SELECT
                                       `reputation`
                                     FROM
                                       `stats`
                                     WHERE
                                       `id` = '".$the_members['id']."'
                                  ")
                                     or die(mysql_error());
```

Then we have to add all the players power together for the groups power.
So far the code I have shown isn't working and after that I need away to add the power.

Would be great for some help!

Comment: This is an `INNER JOIN` as described in this doc page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html.  Basically you got two tables with columns that match and every time they match you get the corresponding row from each put together.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use a single query instead of two separate ones ?

```
SELECT `reputation` 
FROM `stats` 
WHERE `id` in ( SELECT `id` 
                FROM `user` 
                WHERE `group`='".$group."'" )
```

or even easier, using a join:

```
SELECT `reputation` 
FROM `stats` s
JOIN `user` u ON u.`id` = s.`id`
WHERE u.`group`='".$group."'"
```

Comment: OK so i tried this
 $the_member = mysql_query("SELECT `reputation` FROM `stats` WHERE `id` in ( SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `union`='".$id."'" ) or die(mysql_error());
echo "Test" . $the_member['reputation'];

And i got this error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1